# Preparing Segue on a back button of a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to download data before segueing back from a navigation controller, however, my prepareforsegue is not waiting for the information to be downloaded. Shouldperformsegue is not even being called.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    print("prepareforsegue")
    reloadProgram() { (result:String) -> () in
    print("reloaded")
    }
}

func reloadProgram(completion: (result:String)->()) {
    defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "gotColl")
    if defaults.arrayForKey("selectedArray") != nil {
        let selArray = defaults.arrayForKey("selectedIDArray") as! [String]
        Networking().getVideos(selArray) { (result:String) -> () in
            defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "gotColl")
        }
    }
    completion(result: "done")
}
```

Does anybody have an idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Just quickly looking at it, the completion should be inside the Networking scope, no? Just after defaults.setBool, in the same scope.

Comment: shouldperformsegue only works when the segue is not programatically performed (performSegueWithIdentifier...), I'll perform the network operation before calling the segue, and once it's finished, call it

Comment: Eric, that completion belongs to the reloadprogram function

Answer (score 2):

PrepareForSegue is not called from back Button. It is called only when you push/present your controller.

A solution would be to add your own back button with custom action :

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(backTapped:)];
```

And when is tapped call your method

```
-(void)backTapped:(id)sender {
    reloadProgram()
}
```

Comment: according to my print statement, it is being called. The problem is that its not waiting for the networking method to finish.

Comment: Ok, then you can dissmiss your controller in getVideos completion handler. As getVideos is asynchronous method it is non blocking and will not wait for videos to download.